# Continuing at the end of the previous match in RegEx (PCRE)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to prevent the \G anchor from matching the beginning of the string.  I only want it to match at the end of the last regex match.

Given the following text:

```
Pig, Cow, Goat
fruit: apple, orange, peach, pear
vegetable: Carrot, Lettuce, Cellery
```

And this pattern:

```
(fruit:|\G)([\w]+|[\, ])
```

I want it to only match words after "fruit:", but I need it to capture each word individually.  If I just put a + at the very end of this pattern, it would match all the words after "fruit:" but it would only capture "pear" as each iteration of + stomps on the last.

Here's the problem.  This pattern works, except it also matches "Pig, Cow and Goat" because \G will match the end of the last match OR the beginning of the whole string. How can I prevent it from matching the beginning of the whole string?

I'm using PCRE in PHP and I've been using Rubular.com to help me do quick tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my eye, you're regex was not giving you what you said you wanted. You said you wanted each word following "fruit: ". Given your example, I don't think your first attempt was really giving you that.  Try:

```
(?:fruit:\s*|\G,\s*)(\w+)
```

If you match all, that *should* give you the words without the whitespace or punctuation.

Here's a rundown:

- `(?:` - start non-capturing group
- `fruit:\s*` - the preamble for a good match
- `|` - or
- `\G,\s*)` - the last match position, a comma and zero or more whitespace
- `(\w+)` capture one or more word characters

**EDIT:**

To prevent the case where you get a match on the first line, if the first line starts with a comma followed by one or more comma-separated words, just add a negative zero-width look-behind on the start anchor just before the `\G`:

```
(?:fruit:\s*|(?<!^)\G,\s*)(\w+)
```

Comment: Where this has helped me is that you've included the delimiter `,` after the `\G`. Interesting idea.  My problem is that the delimiter and the space are optional.  With them being optional, this pattern could easily start matching from the beginning of the document `Pig` which I have no control over. I also didn't explain that I'm using `preg_replace` and I'd like to match the word `fruit:` separately so I can return it to it's place using the replace string. Hence I didn't use `?:` in my pattern.

Comment: Just throw parentheses around fruit to capture it. With regard to the delimiter and space being optional, how, then, would you separate the words?

Comment: One other thing... the \G for me, at least how I put it in the pattern above, does not seem to be capturing the beginning of a line, unless it is the very first line, and that very first line starts with a comma.  Are you using some options that you have not mentioned? "Dot matches newline"? "^$ match at line breaks"?

Comment: To begin with, your suggestions have helped a lot and I think it solved my problem. To answer your comments: The words may be separated by a comma, forward-slash or back-slash and there may be a space before and/or after that punctuation.  I'm parsing text files converted from PDF's created by others, so I have to be prepared for all kinds of stuff.  You're right that \G isn't matching the start of the document unless it starts with a comma which I hope won't happen.  So I think this will work for me.